# How to change TextInput text after pressing button

Tags: python, kivy

What should I do to see `123` text after pressing `Button` `'Show 123'`?

It works when I uncomment `Clock.schedule_interval` but I need this text to be editable. I see both prints `"trigger"` and `"show"` but the text `'123'` is not shown in the input.

I need it to work with the two classes.

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'multisamples', '0')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

kv = '''
#:import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition
ScreenManagement:
    transition: FadeTransition()
    Show:

<First>:               
    Button:
        text: "Show 123"
        on_press: root.trigger_show()
<Second>:
    TextInput:
        id: textinput                
<Show>
    BoxLayout:
         First:
        Second:
'''

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

class Show(Screen):
    pass

class First(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def trigger_show(self):
        print("trigger")
        s = Second()
        s.show()

class Second(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        #Clock.schedule_interval(self.show, 1)

    def show(self): #(self, dt):
        print('show')
        self.ids.textinput.text = '123'

sm = Builder.load_string(kv)

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Second created within trigger_show is different from the one created in the .kv, that is, it is setting the text in a widget that is not shown and is temporary since it is a local variable.

When creating classes you must expose the signals or events of internal elements throughout the class. In this case I will expose the event on_press of the Button to the First, and the text property of the TextInput to Second, then we make the connection in a scope where both elements exist:

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'multisamples', '0')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

kv = '''
#:import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition
ScreenManagement:
    transition: FadeTransition()
    Show:

<First>:               
    Button:
        text: "Show 123"
        on_press: root.dispatch('on_press')
<Second>:
    text: ""
    TextInput:
        id: textinput  
        text: root.text              
<Show>
    BoxLayout:
        First:
            on_press:
                second.text = "123"
        Second:
            id: second
'''

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

class Show(Screen):
    pass

class First(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.register_event_type('on_press')
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_press(self):
        pass

class Second(BoxLayout):
    pass

sm = Builder.load_string(kv)

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```